# React-native-gesture-handler combined with a react-native-slider

Tags: react-native

I'm using the react-native-reanimated lib together with react-native-gesture-handler to zoom some elements on the screen.
I've added a react-native-slider inside their shared parent component, to give some extra help (if the item is too small it's hard to pinch it).
I can pinch the element and then slide it, but then I can't go back again to the pinchGestureHandler, the image become zoomable only with the slider.

```
Export default class Zoomable extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.zoomableItem = props.zoomableItem;
this.Z = new Value(1);
const offsetZ = new Value(1*this.moveableItem.lastScale);

this.handleZoom = event([
  {
    nativeEvent: ({ scale: z, state }) =>
      block([
        cond(eq(state, State.ACTIVE), set(this.Z, multiply(z, offsetZ))),
        cond(eq(state, State.END), [set(offsetZ, multiply(offsetZ, z))]),
      ]),
  },
]);

}

componentDidUpdate(){

props.slider.value ? this.Z = props.slider.value : null

}


render() {

return (

  <Animated.View style={[Styles.container,{transform: [{ scale: this.Z }] } ]}>      
        <PinchGestureHandler
          ref={this.pinchRef}
          onGestureEvent={this.handleZoom}
          onHandlerStateChange={this.handleZoom}>
          <Animated.Image style={Styles.image} source={{ uri: '' }}/>       
        </PinchGestureHandler>
   </Animated.View>
);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*this.Z* is an animated object so I forgot to assign it a new value with the proper method:

```
this.Z.setValue(props.slider.value)
```